# Is there a way to view Unicode values in the "Emoji and Symbols"?

Tags: emoji, unicode

The emoji and symbol window is good for inserting into documents, but when I need the actual Unicode values, it isn't anywhere in the UI. Is there any way to get those information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Emoji & Symbols panel, top left there's a gear icon. It looks greyed- out always but it's not.

Customise List... scroll right down, Reveal Code Tables & Check Unicode.

The unicode values will then appear in the preview pane for all characters

[image]